# strings not appended onto the file in shell scripting

Tags: shell

I was trying a simple shell program as below to append data at the end of the file,

```
path="/root/dir"
secure="*(rw,..)"
echo "$path $secure" >> a.txt
```

is not appending the string to a.txt

Comment: Is it not appending anything to `a.txt`? Can you show output of `ls -l a.txt`?

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 25 Aug  4 07:44 a.txt

Comment: cat a.txt
adasdasdasasd
adasdasdas

Comment: Are you logged in as root?

Comment: Yes. I'm logged-in as root

Comment: Can you run `date > a.txt` and see if that works

Comment: It works. Also the cmd echo "note book" >> a.txt appends the data at the end. But the echo "$path $secure" >> a.txt fails

Comment: Hmm ok and how about `echo "$path" >> a.txt`

Comment: This is working fine now.

Comment: Could it be that the `*` is giving problems? What if you try to set `secure` with some content that does not contain asterisk? In bash, `*` is expanded. You could also try `secure='*(rw,..)'` (single quote), so that it does not expand.

Comment: * is not the problem. But after dos2unix conversion, it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess but your script may be in DOS format that you're actually trying to write output to `a.txt\r` instead. Try to run one of the following to your code and try again:

```
sed -i 's|\r||' file
dos2unix file
```